# Responsive iframe video list centered horizontal and max-width

Tags: html, css, video, iframe, responsive

I have read through a sizable number of posts with regard to responsive iframe integration both here and elsewhere in google, but nothing has solved my specific problem. I'm throwing in the towel and I need help.

The Goal:
To create a responsive horizontally oriented center justified list of three (or more) youtube videos that has a max-width, and max-height (400 x 225) but can shrink below the max values responsively.

Where I am:
I have created a responsive vertically oriented list of three youtube videos each within their own responsive container; however, I can not for the life of me get the iframes to orient horizontally and centered within the video container while remaining responsive.

What I've tried:
(float: left; float: right; display: inline-block; align: left; align: right; padding: margin:) ETC. I have plugged CSS into the html itself, and into the CSS include file and tested many permutations and combinations of them all to no avail. Not withstanding, I have researched this, on google, and while I've found similar scenarios, I've not come across a solution to this particular variation.

The result:
I can either make a non-responsive horizontally center oriented list of videos laid out as it should look, yet refuses to resize responsively, OR I can make a max-width responsive list of videos that resizes correctly with whatever viewport it's being viewed in, yet is stubbornly left justified and vertically oriented. I just can't seem to get the best of both.

The code:::

From the CSS include:

```
.video{
    color: #927c5a;
    font-family: "Impact", Impact,charcoal, sans-serif;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    }        
.videoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 205px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 225px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    }
.videoWrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 225px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    }
```

From the HTML file:

```
<div class="video">
  <div class="videoWrapper">
    <iframe  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/o6l14SkYtaY?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

 <div class="videoWrapper">
   <iframe  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/o6l14SkYtaY?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

 <div class="videoWrapper">
   <iframe  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/o6l14SkYtaY?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if is this you want...

```
.video {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}

iframe {
   max-width: 400px;
   max-height: 225px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

And drop the `.videoWrapper` additional `div`.

Comment: Not quite, but it is closer. I solved the  responsive float left while maintaining its max-size issue earlier this morning with margin: auto; of all things. So the only thing it's not doing now is centering. I plugged in your css snippets just now but still no dice with getting it to center. 
Also, in your code, it still stacks vertically, even though it is centered. If you add the max-height: 400px; and max-width: 225px; to the .video { selector they snap horizontally, which is something I discovered this morning as well. Thanks for the input amigo.

Comment: You saved my night with this one @Chasen - Thanks!